# The best method to do background tasks with?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler, runnable

Before moving on with my project I thought what I should use to run tasks in background.

The `Activity` has to do following on button hold - `play audio`, `record video`, `record user voice input`, `move graph(set new coordinates with each iteration)`.

At the moment I am using `MediaPlayer` built in `ASync` for `playing audio`. `RunOnUiThread` with `Runnable` for `audio recording` and `Handler` for moving graph and I haven't gotten to `recording` video yet. The UI should be updated after every 3 or 5 ms.

My question is what would be the best option to use in this situation.

This is my audio recording and pitch detection:

```
    AudioDispatcher dispatcher =
            AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(44100,2048,0);



    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e){
            final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    noteText.setText(micInputResult.processPitch(pitchInHz));
                    pitchText.setText("" + pitchInHz);
                    gameView.setSingerArrowY(micInputResult.processPlayerCoordinate(pitchInHz));
                    gameView.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 44100, 2048, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);

    Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
    audioThread.start();
```

And moving graph:

```
        playRecordButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionevent) {
            final int action = motionevent.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                playMedia(songIndex);

                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        //Setting new coordinates for graph on each iteration
                        assa.setMinX(orderNr);
                        assa.setMaxX(orderNr+5);


                        graph.invalidate();
                        if(pitchesList.size() != orderNr){
                            orderNr++;
                        }
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                    }
                };

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.i("repeatBtn", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                assa.setMinX(-2);
                assa.setMaxX(2);
                graph.invalidate();
                orderNr = 0;
                stopAudio();

            }//end else
            return false;
        } //end onTouch
    }); //end b my button
```

I am aware that they should ultimately be ran at once but that is the reason for asking because I have tried many different ways but I am not sure which I should use.

Comment: If you have some background task that will call the UI thread on completion, I think `AsyncTask` is your best choice.

Comment: It would have to update the UI almost after every 3-5 ms

Comment: search for rxjava you won't find better and cleaner solution to do background task

Comment: @SamuelEminet will see what I can find on it

Comment: `The UI should be updated after every 3 or 5 ms.` - that wouldn't happen anyway unless you've found a way of doing 200fps? Have you benchmarked how long each update takes?  Threading is irrelevant if it takes 100ms to perform the task - this makes it a performance issue. Also an `AsyncTask` is just an abstraction over a worker `Thread` using handlers, messages and runnables under the hood to post back to the main UI `Thread`.

Comment: @MarkKeen well no but if you can imagine an app similar to guitar hero vocal, where it registers the user input pretty often and also moves the bar which shows where you have to sing. How should i be able to do that?

Comment: `well no` - if you don't have any metrics on how long this takes I suggest that you perform some benchmarking tests, remember there are 1000's of different Android devices as well, all with varying performance, so if performance is critical this might become a major problem. Sorry no idea what the app you mentioned is.

Comment: @MarkKeen I am not sure if I am allowed to post links here but something like this if you skip past the intro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-xpFRcvCD8    (without the background)